# Lucene 6.0.0 deleting document from index

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

I'm trying to delete a document from a Lucene index I created. And my delete code looks something like this :

```
public void delete(String fname, String index_path)
   {
        try {
            Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
            QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(LuceneConstants.FILE_NAME, analyzer);
            Directory indexDirectory = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(index_path));
            IndexWriterConfig iwg = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
            iwg.setMaxBufferedDeleteTerms(1);
            iwg.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.APPEND);
            IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(indexDirectory,iwg);
            writer.deleteDocuments(new Term(LuceneConstants.FILE_NAME,fname));
            writer.forceMergeDeletes();
            writer.commit();
            writer.flush();
            System.out.println(writer.hasDeletions());
            writer.close();
            System.out.println("Deleted File :"+fname);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(IndexHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(IndexHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
   }
```

I have tried executing the above code with and without `forceMergeDeletes` and both show me `hasDeletions` as false. Is there something wrong with my code ?
I also tried opening the IndexReader in a new program to search to check if there are any delays to delete the file but I am able to search in the deleted file. When i try to delete documents using query, the whole index is deleted (even in APPEND mode) and I am sure the filenames are different for each document in the index. I am  new to Lucene if someone can help me it would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be careful using an analyzed query to delete.  Remember that `deleteDocuments` will delete *all* search results when running the query, regardless of score, not just the best or first result.

Let's say you are trying to delete a file at path:  "/rootdirectory/testfile.txt"

The analyzed query will look like:  `filename:rootdirectory filename:testfile.txt`

So if all your documents filenames are somewhere in "rootdirectory", then yes, they will all be deleted.

Comment: Is there anyway I can do an exact match search with a filepath ? say a file path like `C:/Folder/filename` .  I've noticed that with the standard analyser I am not able to search by filepath even though I've indexed it. `Folder/filename` works fine but once I add the root directory `C:` , no docs are found.

Comment: @SH_V95 Sure, indexing it without analysis (ie. as a StringField) is the typical way to get exact matches on non-textual strings.

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed . Thank you!